# Find String in BST

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I have built a BST that holds album names and years and It constructed according to years.But I want to enter album names and it should give a year. 
So I built this code part :

```
int FindString(treeAlbum *node,char albumTitle[])
{

    FindString(node->Left,albumTitle);
    FindString(node->Right,albumTitle);
    if(!strcpy( node->albumTitle, albumTitle))
    {
        return node->year;
    }
}
```

And treeAlbum struct

```
struct treeAlbum{
        char albumTitle[100];
        int year;
        struct treeAlbum *Left;
        struct treeAlbum *Right; 
}
```

Finally, This code give an error ( Segmentation Fault). How can I fix this ? Thank You.

Comment: We need more information to tell what the actual problem is. First try to load it in gdb and get a line number for where the problem is in your code.

Comment: @JesusRamos I can debug my code. The other part of code is correctly working.This part have an error.

Comment: That's what debugging is... finding the errors and fixing them. Clearly you can't debug your code if not you would not be asking this question.

Comment: You are right @JesusRamos :) I am a new in that topic.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess for the segmentation fault is that you aren't checking for your base case.

```
int FindString(treeAlbum *node,char albumTitle[])
{
    if (!node)
    {
        // Return something sane here
        return ERROR_NOT_FOUND;
    }

    FindString(node->Left,albumTitle);
    FindString(node->Right,albumTitle);
    if(!strcpy( node->albumTitle, albumTitle))
    {
        return node->year;
    }
}
```

However, your code has some other issues:

1. What are you doing with the return values from the recursive calls to `FindString`.  Right now you're not doing anything.
2. You're using `strcpy`, but you probably mean `strcmp`.
3. You have a binary search tree, but you're doing a post-fix search.  This is linear in the size of your tree, but you should be able to use the sorted-ness of the BST to get a log(n) binary tree search.  Namely, look at the album at the current node, and see if you're done, should search left, or search right.

Comment: @Micheal I try to do  what you say.But My code stil give segmentation fault. In your opinion What is rational code which do what I want ?

Comment: I'm not sure because I don't know what your code looks like now.  Check your pointer dereferences to make sure you can't reach code without first ensuring that the pointer is valid.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you do in `FindString` is call `FindString` again with `node->Left`. Either `node->Left` eventually is `null` (if your tree is correctly constructed) which will cause a segfault or it is an earlier node in the tree (in which case your recursion will cause the stack to fill up). Checking for the null case is certainly required!

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `strcmp`, not `strcpy`.  You should evaluate the result of two `FindString()` calls and continue only, when they failed.